# rendering result comes out blurry

Tags: rendering, particles, camera

I've checked the rendering and camera setting, but I can't fix the problem.
The rendering image comes out blurry.
Is this because of the hair particle?

File is below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkvqa5kmibsjurh/nekoonly.20230526.blend?dl=0

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Yes it looks like this is the hair, but the Denoise also tends to blur the silhouette, so maybe try without denoise

Answer (score 0):

Yes the hair tends to make it more blurred. But also you've enabled the *Render > Sampling > Denoise* option, it will tend to blur the parts of the image that seem messy, like the ones with the hair, so in that case maybe you should disable it (or at leat test the parameters). On the left, *Denoise* deactivated, on the right, activated:

[image]